# CakePHP 2.2.2 Auth use not loging users in?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have posted my routes, user model, user controller, app controller and pages controller. This is almost a complete copy of the Simple Authentication guide found for CakePHP 2 on their website.

I am using 2.2.2 and can not seem to get anything to work. The main issue I am been having is that a lot of guides / help assume that you are building this as a new 'base' site, by that I mean that Cake is installed to the root of the hosting. But in my case its not, I am building it as part of a showcase to show what I can do.

The problem with this is that it only reloads the main page (the page that the login form is on). It will not take a valid user + password and do anything with it, same goes for invalid details. So I am doing something basic wrong? Or becuase of the config of trying to have many different projects / sites hosted within the same domain do I need to change something some where?

I have not posted the code for the form I am using on take the users name + password but I have not changed this from what the guide posted.

If you need anything else that I might have not thought to post, then please let me know.

Please help me.

**My Routes Config**

```
$SiteBase = '/projects/cake/DrWho/';

Router::connect($SiteBase, array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect($SiteBase . 'login/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'LogIn'));

Router::connect($SiteBase . 'gallery/', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect($SiteBase . 'episodeguide/', array('controller' => 'episodes', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect($SiteBase . 'forum/', array('controller' => 'forumtopics', 'action' => 'index'));

//Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS. 'routes.php';
```

**My UsersModel**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {

  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
  }

  public $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'username' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'fristname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'surname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'active' => array(
        'boolean' => array(
            'rule' => array('boolean'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'role_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
  );

  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Role' => array(
        'className' => 'Role',
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
  );
}
```

**My UsersController**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class UsersController extends AppController {

public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
}   

public function logout() {
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
}

public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
}

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}

public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    }
}

public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
```

}

**My AppController**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
  public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')
    )
  );
  var $helpers = array('AssetCompress.AssetCompress');

  function beforeFilter() {

  if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
    $this->isMobile = true;
    $this->set('isMobile', true );
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->layout = 'mobile';
  }   
  $this->MenuSystem();

  } //End of beforeFilter function

  function MenuSystem() {
  $this->loadModel('Menu');
  $MenuSQL = $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array('active' => true)));
  $this->set('Menu', $MenuSQL);
 } //End of MenuSystem function

} //End of AppController Class
```

**My PagesController**

```
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

 class PagesController extends AppController {

  public $name = 'Pages';
  public $uses = array();

  function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
  }

  function index() {
    $this->render('pages_home');
  }

  public function display() {
    if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
    $this->render('pages_mobile');
    } else {
    $this->render('pages_home');
    }
  } //End display() function

    } // End of PagesController Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your cake project is inside folder `DOCUMENT_ROOT/projects/cake/DrWho/` (where DOCUMENT_ROOT is your webserver's document root).

You don't have to do anything special to make a cake project work inside a subfolder in document root. Trying to prefix the $siteBase to your routes is actually whats causing problems. The base url is automatically handled by cake. In the rare occasion where the base url isn't guessed properly you can use the `App.baseUrl` config in your `app/Config/core.php`.

Comment: I think this is the right way about doing it but I did it my way becuase when I try to use (and have just re checked) the 'app.baseUrl' all it does it try to look for a projects controller? What I did was the remove my $siteBase from all the rotuing and then uncommented the app.baseUrl but again its just looking for a projects controller? I think because the path starts with project/...